# Bitwise Not - Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a hex number: `0x01F4`

I need the one's complement - which should be `FE0B`. But I can't seem to get what I need.

I do:

```
var n:int = 0xF4;
n = ~n;
trace(n.toString(16));
```

And get `-F5` instead of `0B`.

Anyone know what I can do?

Comment: it's math. I don't know AS3, but I can argue: int is a signed int, your **positive** number F4 is bitwise negated (bitwise not), and the result interpreted again as an integer signed number, which has -F5 as the correct hex signed representation. In the vars, from the bit point of view, there's the right things. If you want to see it, you should cast the int into unsigned int, if it makes sense in AS3 - don't forget: doing 1's complement the "width" is important: how many bits make an int in AS3? (e.g. 32, not 16)

Comment: Ah, that was it! Thank you! All I needed to do was: var n:uint and I get the result I was after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One's complement works on all the bits. In Flash, an int is 32 bits (or 8 hex digits). So `~0x01F4` is `0xFFFFFE0B` (because `0x01F4` is `0x000001F4`). If you want just the last 2 bytes' worth, simply do a mask after: `~n & 0xFFFF`.

The reason you get `-F5` as output is that `int` is a signed type -- so whenever the highest bit is set (as it is with your example), Flash thinks it's a negative 2's complement number and gives you that output. The bits are correct, but the formatted representation is unexpected because you're not asking for what you think you are. Change the type to `uint` and the output should become (the expected) `FFFFFE0B`.